# How to reduce multiple instances of the same value appearing in a table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a table in my app, in which I push many values into an Array. These arrays then show the value within my table columns, at the bottom I have a small example of what I mean. Sometimes it takes double of the same value.

How best do I reduce this so that only one of the same value is present in the ColumnValue Arrays?
Current Code:

```
    methods: {
    caseFileDetailedTableData(row) {
console.log(row=
      return [
        {
          columnName: I18n.t('ccenter.case_file.table.total_debt_outstanding'),
          columnValue: row.totalDebtOutstanding
        },
        {
          columnName: I18n.t('ccenter.case_file.table.company_names'),
          columnValue: row.debtorInfo.companyNames.join(', ') || '-'
        },
        {
          columnName: I18n.t('ccenter.case_file.table.aliases'),
          columnValue: row.debtorInfo.aliases.join(', ') || '-'
        },
        {
          columnName: I18n.t('ccenter.case_file.table.birthdates'),
          columnValue: row.debtorInfo.birthdates.join(', ') || '-'
        },
        {
          columnName: I18n.t('ccenter.case_file.table.phones'),
          columnValue: row.debtorInfo.phones.join(', ') || '-'
        },
        {
          columnName: I18n.t('ccenter.case_file.table.emails'),
          columnValue: row.debtorInfo.emails.join(', ') || '-'
        },
        {
          columnName: I18n.t('ccenter.case_file.table.addresses'),
          columnValue: row.debtorInfo.addresses.join(', ') || '-',
        },
        {
          columnName: I18n.t('ccenter.case_file.table.customer_numbers'),
          columnValue: row.debtorInfo.customerNumbers.join(', ') || '-'
        },
        {
          columnName: I18n.t('ccenter.case_file.table.contract_numbers'),
          columnValue: row.contractNumbers.join(', ') || '-'
        },
        {
          columnName: I18n.t('ccenter.case_file.table.invoice_numbers'),
          columnValue: row.invoiceNumbers.join(', ') || '-'
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Previous Methods Used:

```
     fields.forEach(field => {
            if (participant[field.fieldName].length > 0) {
              const uniqueValues = [];
              const uniqueElements = [];
              participant[field.fieldName].forEach(element => {
                if (!uniqueValues.includes(element.value)) {
                  uniqueValues.push(element.value);
                  uniqueElements.push(element);
                }


...

    removeDuplicateValues(p){
    return Object.keys(p).map(k => Array.isArray(p[k]) ? { [k]: removeDuplicates(p[k]) } : { [k]: p[k] }).reduce((acc, item) => ({...acc, ...item}), {});
    },

    removeDuplicates(arr){
    return [...new Set(arr)];
    console.log(arr)
    },
```

EDIT: Example of Repetition Cited:

```
Date of birth   1982-12-18
Phone numbers   354, 3541914408, 3541914408, 3541914408
```

Comment: Can u show an instancce of repeating values in the table ?

Comment: @leoOrion I've added an example of what I mean, I'm not sure how else to show it.

Comment: Where is ur removeDuplicates method ?

Comment: If u r working on an array of strings use the answer @spender has given. If you are working on an array of objects, create an object out of it like {phone_number: <object>}. This will remove all duplicates(assuming phone number is the only factor for uniqueness). Then iterate over the new object instead of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, a function such as:

```
const removeDupes = (arr) => Array.from(new Set(arr));
```

would do the trick

For instance, for your phone number examples:

```
{
    columnName: I18n.t('ccenter.case_file.table.phones'),
    columnValue: removeDupes(row.debtorInfo.phones).join(', ') || '-'
}
```

Comment: Would this check for uniqueness across the fields of an object in the array ?

Comment: This will not remove duplicates if the duplicate is a field of an object in the array.

Comment: @leoOrion No, but the question seems to suggest that "values" are most likely just strings.

Comment: Oh, i thought since OP had multiple columns he was reading from an array of objects to create each row of the table

Comment: @spender Thank you for your answer, Can you explain how this would work if you don't mind? I've attempted to implement in my code to no avail, but I'm quite new at JS!

Comment: @cbln Sorry, had to step away for a while. Does my edit help?

Comment: @spender It did thanks!